# how to get source code of python print function?

Tags: python

I am trying to get source code of python print using inspect but it is throwing error. Can someone please tell me how to get the source code of python2.7 print statement.

```
inspect.getsourcefile(print)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-6158f5314751> in <module>()
----> 1 inspect.getsourcefile(print)

/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py in getsourcefile(object)
    569     Return None if no way can be identified to get the source.
    570     """
--> 571     filename = getfile(object)
    572     all_bytecode_suffixes = importlib.machinery.DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[:]
    573     all_bytecode_suffixes += importlib.machinery.OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[:]

/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py in getfile(object)
    534         return object.co_filename
    535     raise TypeError('{!r} is not a module, class, method, '
--> 536                     'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
    537 
    538 ModuleInfo = namedtuple('ModuleInfo', 'name suffix mode module_type')

TypeError: <built-in function print> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object

In [86]: inspect.getsourcefile(builtin.print)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-2d1fb60aac58> in <module>()
----> 1 inspect.getsourcefile(builtin.print)

NameError: name 'builtin' is not defined
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/source/ You can find the source to all questions there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `print` function is implemented in C language. That's why you can not reach its source code with the `inspect` module. The code is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1580

Comment: Here's a link to the current source code if anyone's wondering: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1821

Answer (score 1):

There is an [implementation](https://github.com/exebook/generic-print) of `print()` in C. The project has the closest generic implementation of `print()` I've even seen.

And the [cpy](http://github.com/midnqp/cpy) project aims to implement all built-in methods of Python in C most minimally. It should be helpful.