# `<tkinter.Tk>.iconify()` always takes 2 seconds

Tags: tkinter, tcl

Let's say that I want to `iconify` a tkinter window. I would use something like this:

```py
from time import perf_counter
import tkinter as tk

def time(function, *args, **kwargs):
    start = perf_counter()
    function(*args, **kwargs)
    return perf_counter() - start

root = tk.Tk()
root.update() # Make sure that the window appears on the screen
print(time(root.iconify)) # 2.0016179770000235
```

The problem is that it always takes a bit more than 2 seconds for the `.iconify()` to run. Why is that? I looked at [`tkinter`'s source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/adf24bd835ed8f76dcc51aa98c8c54275e86965b/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2109):

```py
def wm_iconify(self):
    """Display widget as icon."""
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconify', self._w)

iconify = wm_iconify
```

and it directly calls `_tkinter` with the parameters. I tried reading `_tkinter`'s source code ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/adf24bd835ed8f76dcc51aa98c8c54275e86965b/Modules/_tkinter.c#L1534)) but I can't find a trace for where the 2 seconds are going. My guess is that the problem is somewhere bellow `_tkinter`.

**Edit**: This issue only effects `Python 3.8.6` + `Ubuntu 20.10` but doesn't appear on `Python 3.7.9` + `Window 10`.

Comment: somethings wrong with the way you are calculating the time. Check this code https://dpaste.com/9HK339MHD Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785243/understanding-time-perf-counter-and-time-process-time

Comment: @BlackThunder It was suggested to me when I has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286367/why-is-my-function-faster-than-pythons-print-function-in-idle) question. `perf_counter` is supposed to be more accurate and it works. Also I forgot to mention that the issue doesn't appear on Windows 10 but it does on Ubuntu 20.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very bottom (there's other bits in between, many of them, but they're all really fast) of Tk's implementation on <del>Unix</del> X11 is [this](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/file?name=unix/tkUnixWm.c&ci=f396601776041086&ln=7414,7418), reproduced here for your convenience:

```c
if (XIconifyWindow(winPtr->display, wmPtr->wrapperPtr->window,
        winPtr->screenNum) == 0) {
    return 0;
}
WaitForMapNotify(winPtr, 0);
```

(The `WaitForMapNotify` is complex, but does what it says on the tin: waiting for a `MapNotify` event from X11.)

It sends a request to iconify and then waits for the Window manager to respond. For some reason, Ubuntu is taking a very long time (2 seconds!) to send that message. I'd describe that as a bug in Ubuntu… unless for some reason you've got some fancy animations enabled and the Window Manager is only finalizing the state change after performing them.

Comment: Thanks. This is were the 2 seconds are going. Btw I have the default setting on my Ubuntu.

Comment: What would happen is `WaitForMapNotify(winPtr, 0)` was removed? That call doesn't look important.

Comment: @TheLizzard Without that, there'll be state inconsistencies. I truly don't know what the consequences of those inconsistencies will be. (The code in question dates from very early in Tk, before the start of our SCM records — things got lost somewhere around 1999.)

Comment: Wow the code is very old. Thanks for the help.